# Android&Quickblox (api 3.2): Subscribing to push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, quickblox

I'm not able to subscribe to push notifications. I did:

1) I created a firebase application, with the same package name as my MainActivity package name;

2) I downloaded the google-service.json file and stored it in my /app/ next to the gradle file;

3) I added the C2D and WAKE-LOCK permissions as the google guide showed;

4) I added the API-KEY in the pushnotification's setting tab in quickblox admin panel;

5) I modified the manifest as showed by the quickblox guide;

6) I added a push-notification listener and a local broadcast receiver as shown by the same guide as above.

That's how my manifest looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="it.unical.sistemidistribuiti.ddf.appraia">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<permission android:name="it.unical.sistemidistribuiti.ddf.appraia.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="it.unical.sistemidistribuiti.ddf.appraia.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.quickblox.messages.TYPE" android:value="FCM" />
<meta-data android:name="com.quickblox.messages.SENDER_ID" android:value="@string/sender_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.quickblox.messages.QB_ENVIRONMENT" android:value="DEVELOPMENT" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="it.unical.sistemidistribuiti.ddf.appraia.AppraiaApplication">
    <activity
        android:name="it.unical.sistemidistribuiti.ddf.appraia.StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="it.unical.sistemidistribuiti.ddf.appraia.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="it.unical.sistemidistribuiti.ddf.appraia.NewsDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="it.unical.sistemidistribuiti.ddf.appraia.CreatePostActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="it.unical.sistemidistribuiti.ddf.appraia.UserProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.quickblox.messages.services.fcm.QBFcmPushListenerService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Since I'm using 3.2 sdk version, the app should automatically subscribe the user to push-notifications, but this not happen. Actually the listener code prints nothing:

```
 //This is in AppraiaApplication extends Application
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    QBSettings.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
    QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);
    QBPushManager.getInstance().addListener(new QBPushManager.QBSubscribeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscriptionCreated() {
            System.out.println("onSubscriptionCreated");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscriptionError(final Exception e, int resultCode) {
            System.out.println("onSubscriptionError" + e);
            if (resultCode >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Google play service exception");
            }
            System.out.println("onSubscriptionError " + e.getMessage());
        }
    });
    QBSettings.getInstance().setEnablePushNotification(true);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(pushBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("new-push-event"));
    System.out.println("Application creation ended");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't make signIn with user, and subscription is not performed. Also have a look in logs, there is can be info something like D/QBASDK: SubscribeService: SubscribeService created. So, you can figure out whether the subscription is executed at all.